# Kubernetes UI Dashboard Not Working

Tags: router, proxy, kubernetes

I'm trying to troubleshoot Kubernetes UI Dashboard. It is not working so far. I have a cluster with three nodes, 1 master and 2 workers:

```
[admin@k8s-node1 ~]$ kubectl get nodes
NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
k8s-master   Ready    master   4d21h   v1.15.2
k8s-node1    Ready    <none>   4d20h   v1.15.2
k8s-node2    Ready    <none>   4d20h   v1.15.2
```

The dashboard is installed using the latest version. All in all, the services appear to be running well (`kube-system` and `kubernetes-dashboard`):

```
[admin@k8s-node1 ~]$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE              NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP           NODE         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system            coredns-5c98db65d4-7fztc                      1/1     Running   2          4d20h   172.16.0.5   k8s-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system            coredns-5c98db65d4-wwb4t                      1/1     Running   2          4d20h   172.16.0.4   k8s-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system            etcd-k8s-master                               1/1     Running   1          4d20h   10.1.99.10   k8s-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-apiserver-k8s-master                     1/1     Running   1          4d20h   10.1.99.10   k8s-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-k8s-master            1/1     Running   1          4d20h   10.1.99.10   k8s-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-router-bt2rb                             1/1     Running   0          30m     10.1.99.11   k8s-node1    <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-router-dnft9                             1/1     Running   0          30m     10.1.99.10   k8s-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-router-z98ns                             1/1     Running   0          29m     10.1.99.12   k8s-node2    <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-scheduler-k8s-master                     1/1     Running   1          4d20h   10.1.99.10   k8s-master   <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-5c8f9556c4-8skmv         1/1     Running   0          43m     172.16.1.4   k8s-node1    <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-metrics-scraper-86456cdd8f-htq9t   1/1     Running   0          43m     172.16.2.7   k8s-node2    <none>           <none>
```

The issue is that when the proxy is activated, the Dashboard does not display on the worker machine (node1) which is the one where Dashboard is running:

URL:

http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

Error Message:

```
Error: 'dial tcp 172.16.1.4:8443: i/o timeout'
Trying to reach: 'https://172.16.1.4:8443/'
```

I'm leaning towards routing, although the routers are all running apparently. Also the log for the dashboard is showing these messages:

```
Metric client health check failed: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get services dashboard-metrics-scraper). Retrying in 30 seconds.
```

Any help is appreciated. I am new to Kubernetes, and this is my first cluster setup so my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you check 2 points i.e.
1. telnet 172.16.1.4:8443 from kubernetes-dashboard pod &
2. Same command from master node
3. If possible please try and install sidecar pod with tcpdump functionality to find out packet transmissions

If all 3 are showing values - you may want to attach to dashboard pod to verify logs printed by that pod.
Btw did it work any time earlier, at all ?

Comment: No, this is a new installation so it hasn't worked before. I guess I don't know kubernetes well enough. How do I telnet from kubernetes-dashboard pod? When I try to list pods using kubectl, I get no pods. When I query kubectl for all namespaces, it appears that kubernetes-pod shows up as a "deployment".

Comment: I tried simulating on my setup. I followed https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/ & it worked. If possible, can you remove existing setup and create once again ?